# After shave itching

Tags: shaving

Every time after shaving underarms I get an itching sensation. Is there is a way to prevent/ reduce it?

It could be something that can be applied before shaving, after shaving or could be a change or improvement of the shaving method/ equipment.

What I have tried so far:

1. Use a shaving machine instead of a razor
2. Apply after shave cologne
3. Used shaving foam instead of soap

All the above-listed methods helped me to improve the situation about 10%, but not more than that. Could anyone suggest an efficient way(s)?

Comment: Do you shave in the same direction the hair grows, sideways, against it or a mix?

Comment: When I was using a razor, I used to raise the hand and move razor from top to bottom. 

When I am using the machine, I move it bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

Try cornstarch after the shave ,ultrafine would be even better (Like the kind found in women's feminine deodorant powder.Its pure cornstarch with a light fragrance but it's always helped me when I'd get the "I think I shaved a bit too close " itch.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. Let me try this next time and let me know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this myself, but wax appears to be very efficient way:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB-F3QA-MTA

The process itself might hurt more than shaving, but as far as I can tell, after it's done there won't be any itching. The above guide is by a female, but applies also for males of course.

Happy waxing! :)

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. I am sorry. I prefer shaving rather than waxing. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hydrocortisone in Over The Counter strength is meant for itches & skin abrasions.  Ask your doctor if in doubt, but it does work to stop itching.